# How to calculate age in query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to calculate the age of the user inside a SQL query. Be aware I splitted the database into the fields: birthday, birthmonth and birthyear.

I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/441b7c) to show what I mean.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_profile` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_birthday` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `user_birthmonth` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `user_birthyear` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `user_profile` 
(user_birthday, user_birthmonth, user_birthyear) VALUES (31, 12, 1990)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you can use the `age()` function

Comment: The logic you want is, first, create a date from the three fields.  Next, get the number of days between that date and the current date.  Divide by 365.25.  The age is the integer portion of the result.  I don't use mySql so I don't know necessary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b0c5a/4/0)**

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday) - (DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d')) AS Age
FROM (
SELECT
 CAST(CONCAT(`user_birthyear`, '-', `user_birthmonth`, '-', `user_birthday`) AS DATE) AS birthday
FROM user_profile ) AS s
```

Comment: Awesome, this did the job. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Piet Happy to hear it helps you :)

Answer (score -3):

Year(getdate()) - birthyear shall be enough

Comment: If someone was born in December 2015, what is their age in January 2016?